# perl remove non ascii chars too slow compared to system call to C program

Tags: c, perl, ascii

I have a perl code that is used to remove non ascii chars and ^M 
But for a 1.5GB file this takes 14 min (On Linux  64 Bit , 16GB RAM , LANG=C set)

I just rewrote the same logic in C and now doing a system call in perl
This is taking only 36s ( Same machine , same file )

Why is this perl code slow (I have tried to replicate a small section of the project ). It takes 30x the time as compared to the C program below

**PERL**

```
my $newfile = $ARGV[0] . ".cleaned";
open(IN,$ARGV[0]) || die "Could not open file $ARGV[0] $!";
open(OUT,">$newfile");
while(defined($c = getc(IN))){
    next if((($i =ord($c)) > 126)  || ($i == 13  ));
    print OUT $c;
}
close IN;
rename($newfile,$ARGV[0]);
```

**C**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv){
  char tmpfile[200];
  FILE *fin,*fout;
  int c;
  snprintf(tmpfile,180,"%s.cleaned",argv[1]);
  fin = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
  fout = fopen(tmpfile, "w");
  while ((c = fgetc(fin)) != EOF) {
    if (c==13 || c > 126) continue;
    fputc(c, fout);
  }
  fclose(fin);
  fclose(fout);
  rename(tmpfile,argv[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: why use perl when you are able to write the same in C ??? just curiosity, please, don't blame me.

Comment: Because the entire project is in perl , I would have to make a system() call only for doing some part of it in C

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reading in chunks of 1M and using `tr///` translation should perform faster than reading one byte at the time,

```
perl -i -pe 'BEGIN{ $/ = \1024**2 } tr|\r\x7F-\xFF||d' file
```

Comment: I have to remove ^M characters too

Comment: That was very fast. As fast as the C program. So I can use the same regex in a perl file ?

Comment: @Ram Yes you can. It is translation and faster than regex.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is "why it happens" it is simply because C is operate at a lower level than Perl, and is known for his efficiency. For the same task C will almost always (I guess) be faster.

Comment: So is it advisable to do a system call in perl for such a task

Comment: But the OS automatically buffers the I/O. I tried reading a large chunk and then doing a tr in perl. That was far worse than 1 char at a time

Comment: How do I avoid per char IO in C ?

Comment: Sorry, downvote.  This is calumnious speculation — you "guess" that C will almost always be faster?  I'd say rather the problem was that the OP naively translated C-style I/O processing into perl, without making use of perl's native I/O and string processing capabilities better suited to the task.